# R: Ask for identification of subset

Tags: r, subset

I have the following subset from a data frame and I want to get the ID numbers (the leftest row), as a vector. How can I do this?

```
> samp[V3=="D",]
   V1 V2 V3  V4
2   A 23  D Arr
3   D 54  D And
4 JAJ 13  D And
```

Thanks

Edit: I mean the `2 3 4`. `V1` are the names.

Comment: Try `samp[V3=="D", ]$V1`

Comment: `samp[V3 == "D", "V1"]`

Comment: try `samp[samp$V3=="D", 1]` or `samp[samp$V3=="D", "V1"]`

Comment: I mean the `2 3 4`, not the `V1`.

Comment: `rownames(samp)`

Comment: Alright, `which(V3=="D")` seems to be OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is:

```
rownames(samp[samp$V3=="D",])
#[1] "2" "3" "4"
```